# Warning: include_once failed to open stream

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Tengo un error al intentar incluir mi vista inicial, usando el patron MVC y POO con PHP. Según el error es que no logra encontrar y/o abrir el archivo template, cosa que no tiene sentido ya que la dirección de la ruta se encuentra bien, si me podeis ayudar con este problema los agradecere.

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function index()
    {
        include_once '../Views/template.php';
    }


Este es mi archivo index
```

```
$index = new RutasController;
$index->index();
```

Esta es mi estructura de mi proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me podais ayudar,si encuentro la solución la compartire con ustedes.

Comment: Por convención las carpetas donde NO almacenes clases no deberías usar letras mayúsculas al inicio, te recmiendo leer un poco sobre PSR-12. En lo personal me ayudó un montón. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: Solo utiliza la etiqueta require en vez de include once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchachos la solución fue muy facil y sencilla, mi error estaba en quitar los dos puntos antes de la carpeta views y especificar la carpeta app. quedaria algo asi.

```
include_once 'App/Views/template.php';
```